# How to close a Tkinter window by pressing a Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

Write a GUI application with a button labeled `"Good-bye"`. When the 
`Button` is clicked, the window closes.

This is my code so far, but it is not working. Can anyone help me out with my code?

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def close_window (root): 
    root.destroy()

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()
button = Button (frame, text = "Good-bye.", command = close_window)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey Matt. Thanks for having a clear question, and a clean and simple code example to accompany. Could you also make sure to include the traceback (crash) in the future when your code is "not working"? That will also help people almost instantly figure out what part of your code is broken. Obviously in this case, your code sample is so small that its easy to identify, but it might really help you get answers in the future on harder situations.

Comment: For anyone not immediately seeing the problem, the error is `TypeError: close_window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'`.  This means that there was no argument passed to the callback `close_window`, as there never is for `command=` functions.  Bound event callbacks do get an argument -- the event object.

Answer (score 38):

With minimal editing to your code (Not sure if they've taught classes or not in your course), change:

```
def close_window(root): 
    root.destroy()
```

to

```
def close_window(): 
    window.destroy()
```

and it should work.

---

**Explanation:**

Your version of `close_window` is defined to expect a single argument, namely `root`.  Subsequently, any calls to your version of `close_window` need to have that argument, or Python will give you a *run-time error*.

When you created a `Button`, you told the button to run `close_window` when it is clicked. However, the source code for Button widget is something like:

```
# class constructor
def __init__(self, some_args, command, more_args):
    #...
    self.command = command
    #...

# this method is called when the user clicks the button
def clicked(self):
    #...
    self.command() # Button calls your function with no arguments.
    #...
```

As my code states, the `Button` class will call your function with no arguments.  However your function is expecting an argument. Thus you had an error.  So, if we take out that argument, so that the function call will execute inside the Button class, we're left with:

```
def close_window(): 
    root.destroy()
```

That's not right, though, either, because `root` is never assigned a value.  It would be like typing in `print(x)` when you haven't defined `x`, yet.

Looking at your code, I figured you wanted to call `destroy` on `window`, so I changed `root` to `window`.

Answer (score 11):

You could create a class that extends the Tkinter `Button` class, that will be specialised to close your window by associating the `destroy` method to its `command` attribute:

```
from tkinter import *

class quitButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Button.__init__(self, parent)
        self['text'] = 'Good Bye'
        # Command to close the window (the destory method)
        self['command'] = parent.destroy
        self.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root = Tk()
quitButton(root)
mainloop()
```

This is the output:

[image]

---

And the reason why your code did not work before:

```
def close_window (): 
    # root.destroy()
    window.destroy()
```

I have a slight feeling you might got the root from some other place, since you did `window = tk()`.

When you call the destroy on the `window` in the Tkinter means destroying the whole application, as your `window` (root window) is the main window for the application. IMHO, I think you should change your `window` to `root`.

```
from tkinter import *

def close_window():
    root.destroy()  # destroying the main window

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = Button(frame)
button['text'] ="Good-bye."
button['command'] = close_window
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10):

You can associate directly the function object `window.destroy` to the `command` attribute of your `button`:

```
button = Button (frame, text="Good-bye.", command=window.destroy)
```

This way you will not need the function `close_window` to close the window for you.

Answer (score 5):

```
from tkinter import *

window = tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

def close_window (): 

    window.destroy()

button = Button ( text = "Good-bye", command = close_window)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lambda` to pass a reference to the `window` object as argument to `close_window` function:

```
button = Button (frame, text="Good-bye.", command = lambda: close_window(window))
```

This works because the `command` attribute is expecting a callable, or callable like object.
A `lambda` is a callable, but in this case it is essentially the result of calling a given function with set parameters.

In essence, you're calling the lambda wrapper of the function which has no args, not the function itself.

Answer (score -2):

```
from tkinter import *

def close_window():
    import sys
    sys.exit()

root = Tk()

frame = Frame (root)
frame.pack()

button = Button (frame, text="Good-bye", command=close_window)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the point is to close an additional window, wheres `sys.exit` will close the whole program.