# Exe still running on window close

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, exe

I'm making a game in Tkinter and I've converted it to an exe using pyinstaller for distribution. When my program is closed, It keeps running in the task manager as a background process, stopping the file from being moved or deleted. I've tried in many ways to fix this such as `sys.exit()` and taskill to try and counter this problem but none work.

Reverting what I've tried, this is my exit code:

```
def rootOnClose():
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit(1)
```

From CoolClouds suggestion, all my buttons in root window:

```
inventorybutton = Button(root, text="Inventory", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=inventory)
inventorybutton.grid(column="0", row="0")

marketbutton = Button(root, text="Market", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=market)
marketbutton.grid(column="0", row="1")

upgradesbutton = Button(root, text="Upgrades", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=upgrades)
upgradesbutton.grid(column="0", row="2")

leftfruitbutton = Button(root, text="<", command=switchleft, state=DISABLED)
leftfruitbutton.place(x="100", y="285")

rightfruitbutton = Button(root, text=">", command=switchright)
rightfruitbutton.place(x="287", y="285")

clickerbutton = Button(root, text="Clicker Button", image=clickerphoto, fg="Black", command=clicked)
clickerbutton.place(x="100", y="75")

musicselectbutton = Button(root, text="Music", command=musicselect, bg="Black", fg="White", width="11")
musicselectbutton.grid(row="4", column="0")

savebutton = Button(root, text="Save", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=save)
savebutton.grid(row="5", column="0")

loadbutton = Button(root, text="Load", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=load)
loadbutton.grid(row="6", column="0")

munchconvertbutton = Button(root, text="Convert Munch", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=convertmunch)
munchconvertbutton.grid(row="7", column="0")

calendarbutton = Button(root, text="Calendar", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=calendar)
calendarbutton.grid(row="8", column="0")
```

with `root` being my Tkinter window.

Solution: Stopping the exe completely with (preferrably) no console and in the quickest way possible. Thanks

Comment: Hi have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987624/how-to-close-a-tkinter-window-by-pressing-a-button

Comment: Im using ```root.destroy()``` correctly however

Comment: can you also upload your buttons

Comment: How come? I will but I dont know how that will help.

Comment: Do you have any background threads running?

Comment: Yes. Not daemon though

Comment: Then try to change the non-daemon thread to daemon thread.

Comment: I have tried. Same problem. I don't think the daemon is working